# Can Adobe Flash Builder be used to debug and profile OpenLaszlo SWF10/SWF11 applications?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, profiling, openlaszlo

I've read that Adobe's [Flash Builder 4.0+ supports profiling of ActionScript 3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7e46.html) applications. Is it then possible to use Flash Builder to profile OpenLaszlo SWFx runtime applications accordingly?

The conversion of OpenLaszlo's LZX source code into an SWF file happens in multiple steps, and  the compiler generates ActionScript source code during this process. How could that source code be used to debug an application inside Flash Builder?

[image]

Based on what I know about Flash Builder, ActionScript 3 applications, and OpenLaszlo it should not be difficult to compile and profile an application once the source code exists. And it should even be possible to debug Adobe AIR for Android applications remotely, shouldn't it?

Comment: This seems feasible. They seem to use the Flex compiler to create the SWF. All you need to do is compile a SWF that has the debug info in it. Not sure if a different SWF is produced while profiling or if the debug SWF is also used.

Comment: If an application is compiled with debug mode active, a different LFC version is used. Since both LFC versions are just SWC files, I guess I have to make sure that you add the correct SWC to your library folder. The SWC files are: $LPS_HOME/lps/includes/LFC10-debug.swc and $LPS_HOME/lps/includes/LFC10.swc (for OpenLaszlo 5.0 trunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [project on Github](https://github.com/raju-bitter/openlaszlo-flashbuilder-project) containing an Ant build script and the required files to profile and debug an OpenLaszlo application with Flash Builder 4.6 on either Windows or Mac.

Here is a screenshot of an OpenLaszlo application running in the profiler:

[image]

I have a created a PDF with a complete tutorial showing how to debug and profile OpenLaszlo SWF11 runtime applications, including the SWF11 LFC classes. The document titled ["Profiling OpenLaszlo Applications with Flash Builder" can be downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/raju-bitter/openlaszlo-flashbuilder-project).

Answer (score 1):

The OpenLaszlo Wiki has a [page with some information](http://wiki.openlaszlo.org/FlexProfiling) on how to compile an SWF to be able to profile the application. You have to compile the LZX file using the command line compiler, e.g.

```
lzc --flex-options=debug --runtime=swf10 your-app.lzx
```

If you use the flex4.6 branch of OpenLaszlo (only [nightly builds available at the moment](http://download.openlaszlo.org/nightly/flex4.6/)), you can compile your app for Flash Player 11, using the swf11 runtime switch:

```
lzc --flex-options=debug --runtime=swf11 my-app.lzx
```

Flash Builder 4.6 is still available for free for a 60 days trial period, but there is only a Windows and OS X version available now (Linux version has been discontinued).

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed that it works with the flex4.6 branch of OpenLaszlo and Flash Builder 4.6. Very useful! Although it would be cool to have the source code attached and to be able to step through the generated ActionScript3 code for debugging.

Comment: I've created a new question regarding debugging OpenLaszlo applications and the LFC classes (with source code and stepping through the ActionScript3 code) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984083